# Appcache manifest - does not load, does not validate

Tags: html, browser-cache, html5-appcache

The example application is here: http://web2485.increo.no, with manifest: http://web2485.increo.no/cache.appcache

The server is configured with the right mime type for .appcache (text/cache-manifest), ref;
http://web-sniffer.net/

At first, the "progress" event were fired 9 times before an "error" event were fired. When trying to explore why the error event fired, all stopped working. Now not even "checking" event is fired. Have tried several browsers.

Chrome says; Creating Application Cache with manifest http://web2485.increo.no/cache.appcache

http://manifest-validator.com/ says;
Line 1: Cache manifest must start with CACHE MANIFEST in first line.

Have tried to clean the manifest with almost no content, and also just "CACHE MANIFEST" as content - and the same errors occur.

(All events and cache status is logged in the "debug" section of the site)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an extra invisible character before the CACHE MANIFEST. Maybe a Unicode BOM?